# How to access wms layer from gwc

Tags: extjs, openlayers, geoserver

I am using openlayers ,geoserver and Extjs, How can i access wms layer properly from geowebcache of geoserver. Now i am using this code

```
                               map.addLayer(
     new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
"trivandrum","http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms",{
                srs:"EPSG:4030",
                LAYERS:'tvm_road_colony',
                Format:'image/png',
                transparent:true,
                tiled: true

            },
            {
                buffer: 0,
                displayOutsideMaxExtent:true,
                visibility: true,

                isBaseLayer: true
            } 
        )
);

        here I have got wms layer but when i try to zoom i did'nt get the layer completely how can i solve this problem? please help
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method of accessing WMS through geowebcache is correct.
Try going to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo`, see if you are able to view the layer demo from there.

Another couple of things to keep an eye out on
- you use  SRS 4030 - make sure that is configured correctly in geowebcache.xml since geoserver/geowebcache does not automatically detect SRS other than 4386 and 900913

If this does not solve the problem, do you get any pink screens? It would also be helpful to get a screenshot to see what your output looks like